# How to reduce LiveData observers code in Fragments?

Tags: android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am refactoring our android code and can't deal with the following issue. Some of our fragments contain too much code (~1000 lines of code).

1. We can dynamically update our boolean flags from the backend.
2. Our fragment **should handle additional UI** depending on boolean flags from the backend.

I am following ViewModel + LiveData style to handle our UI logic. Basically some of our Fragments observe 5-7 different LiveData observables from our VM. Each of LiveData observers produce 20-100 lines of codes. They handle colors changing, the appearance of different dialogs, snack bars, or bottom sheets and etc.

Right now I would like to **reduce code in Fragments,** but I am not sure how should I approach this problem.

One solution which immediately comes to my mind is to use **inheritance**. For instance our fragment **would extend** FragmentFeature2->FragmentFeature3->FragmentFeature4->FragmentFeature5. All of them would observe **particular** LiveData inside of onViewCreated.

Still, I think that inheritance seems like a hacky solution and will cause more issues in the future. Ideally, I would like to have the following scenario:

Our fragment would create a different class per feature, which would act **as a manager for particular LiveData**. Problem is that you can't observe LiveData in a class, **which doesn't have view-lifecycle owner.** Perhaps I am missing something and someone can correct me :)

Answer (score 0):

There may be different approaches according to why you have to write much code in your fragment. If you apply some logic to observed data like if statements etc. you should serve your data to the fragment is presentable form. For this case, you can use live data operators to manipulate the data in reactive way by using maps, mediator live data etc. so you can set the values directly to views. Another case if you already have a simple data in view but setting them takes much line of codes. For this, you can create customViews or customComponents to handle data so you shift your field setting lines to more appropriate place. If the both of the solutions fail to solve your problem you can create a presenter between your view model and view.